# retainAll() for Arraylist<CustomClass>() of custom class not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to use retainAll() for Arraylist of custom class that I have defined. But the resulting arraylist does not contain any value, it becomes empty. Here is the code given below.

```
ArrayList<AllBrandsData> check = new ArrayList<AllBrandsData>(database.getBrandsForGivenKeyword(searchBrand, Brand_Type.Brand));

ArrayList<AllBrandsData> check2 = new ArrayList<AllBrandsData>(brands);

Boolean status = check2.retainAll(check);

System.out.println("Sizes are --> " + check2.size() + " & " + check.size() + " Status is --> " + status);
```

white printing out the check2 size comes out to be zero.
Any help is appretiaited.

P.S - check and check2 are having data in them and they do share some common data.

Comment: could please print value of branks arraylist before `ArrayList<AllBrandsData> check2 = new ArrayList<AllBrandsData>(brands);`

Comment: Does your custom class implement equals()/hashCode()?

Comment: No sir it doesn't. But I would rather filter them easily my own way.
But i was wondering why is it not possible this way? After all they are arraylist objects of same class. right ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to override the following methods in AllBrandsData class and implement the appropriate code:

```
public boolean equals(Object object)

public int hashCode()
```

Comment: But then i would rather do it myself. That would be much easy. But it should have done the job right?

After all they are the arraylist objects of same class ??

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Found some very userful insight on this topic. Was not aware of these things before.
Found some intersting links on this --


1) http://javapapers.com/core-java/hashcode-and-equals-methods-override/

2) http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

3) http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20